# Bundler cannot continue; "error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error whenever installing/updating bundles.

Error: http://pastebin.com/XJ25DHaQ
Full: http://pastebin.com/0A3RUpqu

If anyone can help me fix this issue, that'd be great. Running Mac OS 10.12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should alter the environment variables on your system when installing the MySQL2 gem with the following command:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.0.00' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Note: Just replace the 0.0.00 with the desired version of MySQL2 you wish to install.

Comment: Thank you! No errors anymore- would up vote answer however I'm new to the community.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with macOS Monterey 12.1. So, to solve it, I did:

1 - Install **openssl** using:

```sh
brew install openssl
```

2 - Add this to `.zshrc` file:

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

3 - Update the local `.bundle/config`. There are two options for that:

It's possible to add this to the `.bundle/config`:

```sh
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__MYSQL2: "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro"
```

Or you could type this:

```sh
# MySql
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro"
```

After that, the warnings stopped.